# Weird Segmentation fault with Sockets in C with linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, centos

Currently all I am trying to do is just fix this segmentation fault for a simple client socket connection I am trying to make. I am getting a segmentation fault everytime at the connect() line and I am not sure why. I have tried multiple different implementations of initializing everything to connect, but have had no luck getting around this seg fault.

Here is Client.C code:

```
/*LINUX socket initializations*/

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <errno.h>
int SendingSocket, portno;
struct hostent *server;
int iResult;
int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char response[10];


#define DEFAULT_PORT "2212"
#define DEFAULT_ADDRESS "127.0.0.1"

int main(int argc, char* argv[];) {
/*
* Initializing socket 
*/

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

portno = atoi(DEFAULT_PORT);


SendingSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (SendingSocket < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
server = gethostbyname(DEFAULT_ADDRESS);
if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}

memset(&serv_addr, '0',sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(22041);

printf("got it\n");

in_addr_t in_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
if(INADDR_NONE == in_addr) {
perror("inet_addr() failed");
exit(0);
}
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = in_addr;


if (connect(SendingSocket,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) { 
    error("ERROR connecting");
}

printf("socket is connected!");


}
    /*
    * END socket initialization
    */
```

Here is the error:

```
[asl@asl Bridge]$ ./socket
got it
./socket: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is the output from GDB:

```
/home/asl/Desktop/backup-4-1-20/Bridge/socket: 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strchrnul () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strchrnul.S:34
34      movdqa  (%rdi), %xmm0
```

I am currently in a CentOS 6.8 environment if that helps.

Why is this weird segfault coming from strchrnul? I can't find any information from it. I am using a fairly old OS due to certain reasons...is there a package or something that needs to be updated or is this related to my code?

**EDIT:** This looks like to be an issue with packages/something with my OS. This does not seem to be an issue with my code. I just ran this code and ran it successfully on my raspberry pi running raspbian. Anyone have any idea of what the issue within CentOS could be?

Comment: This looks suspicious: `memset(&serv_addr, '0',sizeof(serv_addr));`.  Perhaps you wanted `'\0'` or just `0`?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Tried both of those options and get the same error :/

Comment: Post your complete code.  I suspect you're using `send()`/`recv()`/`read()`/`write()` to send strings and failing to address the fact that the functions you're using do not terminate strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `error()` incorrectly.  According to the man pages, the function is of the format `void error(int status, int errnum, const char *format, ...);`, but you are just passing a string.  Perhaps you intended to use the `perror()` function?

Also, if it wasn't a copy error, you have an extraneous semi-colon:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[];) {
                               ^
```

Comment: Coincidentally I just figured out that was the issue to, thinks for the help and quick responses.

Comment: Just a quick note pertaining to the solution you found (I saw your answer before you deleted it): `herror()` is considered obsolete according to the man-page on my system.  CentOS 6 is pretty old, though, so its libraries may not have obsoleted it.